# what would be default bindingName in WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, annotations, jax-ws

Like default service name in generated wsdl would be className+Service when we do not specify `serviceName` in `@WebService` annotation. I would like to know what the default binding name would be in generated WSDL from java class through wsgen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JSR 224 Chapter 3, 3.8.1](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr224/index3.html), the default is the services class name with a `Binding` suffix.

> The value of the name attribute of the `wsdl:binding` is not significant, by convention it contains the qualified name of the corresponding `wsdl:portType` suffixed with “Binding”

And the port type name is defined as the service class names with a `Service` suffix.

> [...] the `serviceName` element of the `WebService` annotation are used to derive the service name. The value of the name attribute of the `wsdl:service` element is computed according to the JSR-181 [15] specification. It is given by the `serviceName` element of the `WebService` annotation, if present with a non-default value, otherwise the name of the implementation class with the “Service”suffix appended to it.